# Sum of Array List In groovy

Tags: groovy

I have an Array List in groovy in below format. I want the sum of integer values in this list.

```
[ {"value":1}, {"value":1}, {"value":10}, {"value":11}, {"value":12}]
```

Expected Output

```
1+1+10+11+12=35
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Oh it's very easy.

```
list.value.sum()
```

Comment: @Rotem: This is a documented feature of the language, see http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_gpath_support.

Comment: You can use sum() without value, for example: int[] r = [1,2,3,4] println r.toList().sum()

Answer (score 9):

I would prefer using the [Groovy Spread Operator](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/index.html#_spread_operator).

> The Spread Operator (*.) is used to invoke an action on all items of an aggregate object.

Specific to your question, the best way coding the desired result is:

```
list*.value.sum()
```

The difference is only a * but it is best practice to use the language correctly.